# Android substring force closes

Tags: android

I give up. I use substring a lot but this time I cannot make it work. I am selecting a contact from a spinner (that is populated with the contacts of the phone) and I want the surname of that selected contact. Part of the code:

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
    View view, int pos, long id) {
    selectedname = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    sn = selectedname .indexOf(' ');
    String selectedname2= selectedname.substring(1, 3); //force close line
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

}
```

}

The selectedname and sn variables return real values.
e.g. the

```
    BtnOK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
BtnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(Alarm.this, "selname: " + selectedname + "-" + sn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

returns selname: Anna-4

But if i include the `String selectedname2= selectedname.substring(1, 3);` line, it force closes.
Any ideas?

Logcat:

```
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1579)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at com.bfarago.app.Alarm$MyOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(Alarm.java:577)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:864)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:830)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-04 17:05:32.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 577 is `String selectedname2= selectedname.substring(1, 3);`

This line would be   `String selectedname2= selectedname.substring(1, sn);`, i was just trying to figure out what is wrong.

**Edit2: Whole code:**

```
public class Alarm extends Activity {

    public ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();   
    String contactName;
    int spaceIndex, spaceLastIndex, spaceIndex2;
    String selectedname;
    String selectedname2;
    int sn;
    int selnamelength;
    String[] words;
    String surname;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.alarm);

contactName = null;
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

while (cursor.moveToNext())
{
    contactName  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
    spaceIndex =  contactName.indexOf(' ');
    spaceLastIndex =  contactName.lastIndexOf(' ');
    if (spaceIndex > 0)     {myArr.add(contactName);}
    else if (spaceLastIndex > 0)        {myArr.add(contactName);}
    else      {myArr.add(contactName);}
}
myArr.add("");
Collections.sort(myArr);

Spinner sp1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
final ArrayAdapter adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArr);
sp1.setAdapter(adapter3);
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
        selectedname = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        sn = selectedname.indexOf(' ');
        selnamelength = selectedname.length();
        selectedname2 = selectedname.substring(1, 3);  //force closes

        if (!selectedname.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(Alarm.this, "selectedname.length = " + selnamelength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //This is working
        }

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

    }
}
}
```

By the way, split() function is working...

Comment: Can you be more specific? ( For splitting strings string.split(" ") seems to be better).

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
String selectedname2 = new String(selectedname.substring(1, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this?

```
String selectedname2= selectedname.substring(sn, selectedname.length());
```

also try to log your exception, look at LogCat or put a try/catch block and Log your exception to give us more details.

[Edited]

Please copy all your activity code, the selectedname var is declared at the activity scope. Try to declare this var in the method scope, it seems that this var is being modified in another part of your activity.

You're getting an IndexOutOfBoundException:
[image]

So the reason is because the selectedname content was changed before the line#577. First try to declare this var at method scope, then copy&paste your fully activity code so I can see where this var is used.
**Remember that a substring method shares the [string's backing array](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#backing_array), so any modification in the substring will affect your original string, an then your string array.**

Comment: Any ideas? I was struggling with this for hours yesterday. The selectedname variable is valid, and if I include selectedname.substring(sn, selectedname.length()); in a toast msg it gives me right value but if i use it as a variable it force closes. It's really annoying

Comment: Method scope? Sorry, what is that? I declared it in the onCreate() method, but i don't think it should be declared there because when it gets a value only after I selected an item in the spinner. So in the onCreate method it's value is null. I added the full code.

Comment: I created a new proyect with most of your code and works, it's strange. It seems then to be a data related problem, any of your value? Also try to erase this sentence myArr.add(""); and tell me if the error still continues. If the current value to get the substring is this... we got the error, have a nice day

Comment: I still exists, however I am using substring successfully in other parts of the same acitivity. I have no idea what is wrong, but managed to "solve" it by using split.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you use the split function? which is the split character?